# Concatenate string from markup extension (translation) with another string

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, localization, xamarin.forms

I want to translate a string using a [markup extension](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/#Localizing_XAML). This is working so far. Now I want to add a colon and a space. But the app crashes if I open the XAML page. These are my tries:

```
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate Start}: " />
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate Start, StringFormat='{0}: '}" />
```

Any suggestions on how I can concatenate the string from the markup extension with another string? I don't want to add the characters to Resx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This worked](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/203595/#Comment_203595) for me:

```
<Label>
  <Label.FormattedText>
    <FormattedString>
      <Span Text="{i18n:Translate Start}" />
      <Span Text=": " />
    </FormattedString>
  </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

One option is to use [`FormattedText`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.FormattedText/) as can be seen above. Another one would be to use a `Converter` I think.

Comment: If you want to add a binding as your second value, you can't use FormattedString unfortunately.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can do this for a button?